# Call to a member function row() on a non-object

Tags: codeigniter

i am getting error **Call to a member function row() on a non-object** in codeigniter my controller is

```
public function edit_survey_pro($id) 
{
    $id = intval($id);
    $survey = $this->model->get("surveys",array("ID" => $id),100000);
    if (sizeof($survey) == 0) $this->template->error(lang("error_32"));
    $this->template->loadContent("user/edit_survey_pro", array(
        "survey" => $survey->row()
        )
    );
}
```

my model is

```
function get($table,$where='',$perpage=0,$start=0,$order_by='',$arr='')
{
    $this->db->from($table);
    if($perpage != 0 && $perpage != NULL)
        $this->db->limit($perpage,$start);
    if($where){
        $this->db->where($where);
    }
    if($order_by){
        $this->db->order_by($order_by);
    }
    if($arr=='')
            $query = $this->db->get()->result();
    else
            $query = $this->db->get()->result('array');
    if(!empty($query))
        if($perpage != 0 && $perpage != NULL)
            $result = $query;
        else
            $result = $query[0];
    else
        $result = array();
    return $result;
}
```

here loadContent() is just load the content with view path

```
public function loadContent($view,$data=array(),$die=0){
     //something to load the content
}
```

Comment: In your model, your conditionals are checking if your parameters are set, however since you are setting them = "" , they will always be set. fix that.

Comment: why not include the full error message.It might says your line number where you got the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**in my model** I am getting the result as an array of object in `$query` and then it is returned as `$result` like this - 
`$query = $this->db->get()->result();` but **at the controller**  `$survey` stores array of object and i want to show the content of that array of object ,previously I use

```
$this->template->loadContent("user/edit_survey_pro", array(
    "survey" => $survey->row()
    )
);
```

to get that data but the problem is `$survey->row()` cannot return that data bcoz it is not an object it is array of object so it can't be returned through `row()` method

so instead of this I just call the first element of that data like this-

```
$this->template->loadContent("user/edit_survey_pro", array(
    "survey" => $survey[0]
    )
);
```

Somehow its works for me bcoz I want to show the first row of the data 
if sembody wants to show all data then I think he shuld try logic to increment the key value of that array of object for me it is `$survey[]` you can use `foreach` loop for increment the of value of the key element

Answer (score 0):

The problems i see are your model, I will dissect it and add comments to your original code to point out the issues:

```
    function get($table,$where='',$perpage=0,$start=0,$order_by='',$arr='')
    //above there are problems, you are setting some of your parameters to 
    //equal blank, but below, in your conditionals, you are checking if they
    // exist. They will always exist if they are set to blank. Fix them by
    // setting them = NULL like this:
    // get($table,$where=null,$perpage=0,$start=0,$order_by=null,$arr=null)
    {

        $this->db->select();// <-- you forgot this

        $this->db->from($table);

        if($perpage != 0 && $perpage != NULL) 
            //when will $perpage = null? , if never, then you dont need it.
            $this->db->limit($perpage,$start);

        if($where){ 
            //change this to if(isset($where)). Also why do you use 
            //curly braces here, but not in the above if statement if only 
            //one line is affected in your if. I would remove the 
            //curly braces here.
            $this->db->where($where);
        }

        if($order_by){
            // change this to if(isset($order_by)). Same thing as 
            //above about the curly braces here
            $this->db->order_by($order_by);
        }

        if($arr=='')
            // change this to if(isset($arr)).
            $query = $this->db->get()->result();
        else
            $query = $this->db->get()->result('array');
            //change this to: $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();

        if(!empty($query))
        //change the above to if($query->num_rows > 0). Also, here since
        //your code body is longer then one line, you will need curly braces
        //around your if statement
            if($perpage != 0 && $perpage != NULL) 
            //again, will $perpage ever be NULL? However, why do you need 
            //this conditional at all, if the limit above is already 
            //doing this job?
                $result = $query;
            else
               $result = $query[0];
       else
            $result = array();

       return $result;
    }
```

after applying all the changes:

**MODEL:**

```
function get($table, $where=null, $perpage=0, $start=0, $order_by=null, $arr=null)
{

    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from($table);

    if($perpage != 0) 
        $this->db->limit($perpage, $start);

    if(isset($where))
        $this->db->where($where);

    if(isset($order_by))
        $this->db->order_by($order_by);

    if(isset($arr)) {
        $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    } else {
        $result = $this->db->get()->result();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function edit_survey_pro($id) {

    $id = intval($id);
    $survey = $this->model->get("surveys",array("ID" => $id),100000);

    if (!$survey) {
         $this->template->error(lang("error_32"));
    } else {
         $data["survey"] = $survey;
         $this->template->loadContent("user/edit_survey_pro", $data);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but now i am getting new error **Trying to get property of non-object**  in admin_model thanks in advance

Comment: thanks but it not work it still showing :`Call to a member function row() on a non-object` in controller

Comment: the problem is in your controller, your'e still trying to send the results, even though none exist. fix your conditionals. I updated my answer again.

Comment: not working again shows the same error `Call to a member function row() on a non-object `

Comment: where is that showing? what line? maybe I can log in to your machine with Teamviewer to further help you

Comment: wait a sec.. of course it will give you an error. you are still using `$survey->row()` .. this will not work because `$survey` is your results in object form. In other words, `row()` does not exist in `$survey` (you can check the contents using  `var_dump($survey)`). What exactly are you trying to send to your view?

Comment: i am just trying to get the data from table and show in view

Comment: i am just trying to get the data from table and show in view  ,  in my view  something like this `<input type="text" value="$survey->ID" name="userID" />;` and  others value are also like this.  here "ID" is the atrribute in my database

Comment: in that case, what I provided above should work. You might have missed something.

Answer (score -1):

I think when you use `$this->db->get()`, you need to pass the table name as param like this:

```
$this->db->get('table_name')->result();
```

Comment: i think its not work bcoz table is already getting from code  `$this->db->from($table);`  i think the error is shown bcoz the $survey variable is storing an array element but row() method expecting to it is an object type